# Calculate $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+\frac{x^{4}}{n}}dx$ if it exists.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Calculate $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1+\frac{x^4}{n}} \, dx$$
if it exists. If this limit does not exist, show why it does not exist.

**My attemp:** Consider $f_n(x):=\frac{1}{1+\frac{x^{4}}{n}}$,  since $f_n$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$, then $f_n$ is $f_n$ are Lebesgue measurable in $\mathbb{R}$, futhermore, note that $f_n\leq f_{n+1}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Moreover, we have
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }f_n(x)=1.$$
Therefore,. by Monotone convergence Theorem we have
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{1+\frac{x^4}{n}} \, dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{1+\frac{x^4}{n}} \, dx= \int_{-\infty}^\infty 1\,dx=\infty.$$

**Quiestion:** This last conclusion brought me doubts. ***Does the monotone convergence theorem guarantee that the integral exists?*** I have read over and over the theorem and I do not find guarantee the existence, it only allows to enter the limit in the integral. ***I would like to know if I am correct. Additionally, know if there is any error in my attempt and know another way to do it.***

Comment: Please, have a look at an *alternative* route below.

Comment: In the monotone convergence theorem, it is allowed that the integral of the limit function is $+\infty$. Since it deals with non-negative measurable functions, the integral always exists in $[0,+\infty]$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One may write, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+\frac{x^{4}}{n}}dx&=2\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+\frac{x^{4}}{n}}dx
\\\\&=2n^{1/4}\underbrace{\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+u^4}du}_{>0}\qquad \left(u=\frac{x}{n^{1/4}}\right)
\\\\& \to \infty.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 5):

Note that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+\frac{x^4}{n}} \; dx >\int_{-\sqrt[4]{n}}^{\sqrt[4]{n}} \frac{1}{1+\frac{x^4}{n}} \; dx  > \int_{-\sqrt[4]{n}}^{\sqrt[4]{n}} \frac{1}{2} \; dx = \sqrt[4]{n}.$$

Comment: we had exactly the same idea. you beat me by a minute or two, so i'll go ahead and delete my answer

Answer (score 4):

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+\frac{x^4}{n}}\mathrm{d}x=\pi\frac{\sqrt[4]{n}}{\sqrt{2}}
$$

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+\frac{x^4}{n}}\mathrm{d}x=\infty
$$